# Why in Java char X= 89 works but not char X= 'X'+1 even though RHS is integer in both cases

Tags: java, char, type-conversion

This is a basic question to which I am unable to find the answer. I am aware that we can perform the same operation by type casting

char = (char)('X'+1) [or] char X += 1

But why there is a need for conversion when it works when we assign integer directly to char.

Comment: Btw. `char X = 'X'+1;` works without problems, But `X = X + 1;` does not when X is of type char.

Comment: I realized that mistake I meant to put an identifier there instead of char. Now I understood expression with identifier won't work because of the range mismatch between char and integer.